# What is the word for "bluberries" and "cranberries" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, sustantivos, plantas

Two translator Apps indicate "arándanos" for both cranberries and blueberries.

One suggested "arándanos rojos" for cranberries, and "arándanos azules" for blueberries.

What are the words for such fruits in Spanish?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se]. Currently your question is a bit vague, could you [edit] it to clarify what your question is? It may be of good help to check [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm taking as granted that you want to know the difference between cranberries and blueberries in Spanish.

- The [cranberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry) refer to several species within the subgenus *Oxycoccus* of the genus Vaccinium. Its equivalent in Spanish is **[arándano rojo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar%C3%A1ndano_rojo)**.
- The [blueberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueberry) refer to several species from the section *Cyanococcus* within the genus *Vaccinium*. One of those species, the *vaccinium corymbosum*, is what we know as **[arándano azul](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccinium_corymbosum)** or just **arándano**. Nonetheless, it seems that the word *arándano* in Spanish refers to the *[vaccinium myrtillus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccinium_myrtillus)*, a species known in English as bilberry or European blueberry. In fact, the Spanish definition for *[arándano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3OtO9Li)* in the DRAE takes as granted that the fruit of the bush is blackish or bluish.

Comment: I looked in the Oxford Spanish/English dictionary, and in the English section cranberry and blueberry both point to arándano, but in the Spanish section the word arándano just points to blueberry and bilberry.  And how would you say "That sports car color was cranberry"?  Also, would cranberry juice (quite common in the grocery store) be "jugo de arándano rojo" or what?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The common translations are "arándanos rojos" and "arándanos azules"

In this [page](https://respuestanatural.net/2013/04/06/717/) you could find more info in Spanish.

Both berries have this scientific names '*Vaccinium oxycoccus*' for "*rojos*" and '*Vaccinium corymbosum*' for the "*azules*" where the whole vaccinium family is called in Spanish "*arándanos*" o "*bayas*".

There are more than just blues and reds. There is also other colors like black (it is really dark red or dark purple) and those we call them "*moras*"

If you search images for "bayas" you will see all kinds of berries.

[image]

Comment: Es posible que lo que estáis referenciando en las fotos se llame diferente en vuestra región; pero los frutos rojos que se ven en la imagen, donde yo vivo se les llama "frambuesa" y "grosella" respectivamente. Buscando por internet, veo bastante confusión con los términos, y me parece interesante

Comment: @Jalo Estoy de acuerdo. Existen nombres regionales. Igual, la imagen es tomada de un sitio que habla mucho sobre el tema. En Colombia las  casi negras se llaman moras, las rosadas también frambuesas, las otras si las llaman arándanos. De todas formas todas son bayas y de la familia Vaccinium que en inglés es la familia "berries". Sumando las fresas tenemos blackberries, cranberries, blueberries, raspberry, strawberries. Lo de la grosella es otro tema. En inglés se dice "currant" y a diferencia de todas las bayas, viene de un arbusto y no es de la familia `vaccinium` sino de la familia `Ribes`

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Muchas gracias @DGaleano